# "Almost geodesics" in Riemannian manifolds which cannot be loops

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M,N$ be smooth Riemannian manifolds of the same dimension.  Let $0<\varepsilon<\frac{inj(N)}{100}$. Let $f\colon M\to N$ be a smooth map such that for any $x\in M$ and any $v\in T_xM$ one has
$$(1-\varepsilon)|v|\leq |df_x(v)|\leq (1+\varepsilon)|v|.$$
Let $\gamma\colon[a,b]\to M$ be a geodesic. Denote $\tilde\gamma:=f\circ \gamma$.

**Question. What conditions, formulated in terms of geometry of $N$ only (rather than $M$),  are satisfied by the curve $\tilde\gamma$  which guarantee that if $length(\tilde \gamma)$ is small enough then $\tilde\gamma$ cannot be a loop, i.e.
$\tilde\gamma(a)\ne \tilde\gamma(b)?$**

For example, if $\varepsilon=0$ then $\tilde\gamma$ is also a geodesic, and if $length(\tilde \gamma)<inj(N)$ then $\tilde \gamma$ cannot be a loop.

Sorry if my question is somewhat vague, its precise formulation is a part of the question.

Comment: When you  say that $\bar\gamma$ is "also a geodesic" do you mean to say that $\gamma$ is a geodesic?  This wasn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: Thank you . Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $M$ is complete.
(It is easy to construct counterexamples in the noncomplete case.)

The inverse function theorem implies that the map $f$ is locally invertible;
that is, if $p\in f(x)$, then there is a neighborhood $U\ni p$ and a right inverse $g\colon U\to M$ of $f$ such that $g(p)=x$.
(Here we have to assume that $\varepsilon <1$.)

Now assume $\tilde \gamma=f\circ\gamma$ is a short loop based at $p$.
Consider the geodesic homotopy $\tilde h_t$ from $\tilde \gamma$ to the constant map with image $p$.
This homotopy admits a local lifting $h_t$ to $M$;
moreover, the lengths of lifted curves $t\mapsto h_t(x)$ can be controlled.
Therefore the maximal interval of definition of $h_t$ is a closed subinterval of $[0,1]$.
On the other hand, this subinterval must be open.
Hence $\tilde h_t$ admits a global lifting.
In particular $\gamma$ is a loop --- a contradiction.

Comment: What is geodesic homotopy?

Comment: Here I asked a more precise version of this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463773/when-varepsilon-geodesic-cannot-be-a-loop

Comment: @asv  If $t\mapsto h_t(x)$ is a geodesic path for any $x$, then $h_t$ is called geodesic homotopy. If length of $\tilde\gamma$ is smaller than injectivity radius, then it is defined.