# When "$(\varepsilon,\delta)$-geodesic" cannot be a loop?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

**EDIT:** Let $M$ be a smooth compact Riemannian manifold. Let $\varepsilon,\delta>0$. I call a smooth curve $\gamma\colon [a,b]\to M$ an $(\varepsilon,\delta)$-geodesic if for any $t_1<t_2<t_1+\delta$
one has $$dist(\gamma(t_1),\gamma(t_2))\leq length(\gamma[t_1,t_2])\leq (1+\varepsilon)dist(\gamma(t_1),\gamma(t_2)),$$
where $dist$ denotes the Riemannian distance between the two points, and $length(\gamma[t_1,t_2])$ is the length of the curve $\gamma$ between $t_1$ and $t_2$.

**Question. Given $M$, do there exist $\varepsilon,\delta, l>0$ such that no $(\varepsilon,\delta)$-geodesic of length less than $l$ is a loop, i.e. $\gamma(a)\ne \gamma(b)$?**

Remark. Clearly $0$-geodesics are usual geodesics. If the length of a geodesic is less than the injectivity radius then it cannot be a loop.

This question is a more precise version of ["Almost geodesics" in Riemannian manifolds which cannot be loops](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463707/almost-geodesics-in-riemannian-manifolds-which-cannot-be-loops/463769#463769)

Comment: I believe that there is a "dist" missing from the right-hand side of the displayed equation.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: Oh, and perhaps the following is relevant. If $M$ is negatively curved, and and $\delta$ is not too small, then your condition (locally quasi-geodesic) implies the path is globally quasi-geodesic.

Comment: @SamNead: Quasi-geodesic, this is the standard name of what I called $\varepsilon$-geodesic?

Comment: Your $\epsilon$ geodesics are "$\delta$--local $(1 + \epsilon, 0)$--quasi-geodesics".

Comment: By the way (referring to your second-to-last sentence), your $(0, \delta)$-geodesics are $\delta$-local geodesics, but need not be global geodesics.

Answer (score 2):

Assembling my comments into a partial answer:

You may be interested in the theorem that "in the presence of negative curvature, local quasi-geodesics are in fact global quasi-geodesics".  Here is a MathStackExchange [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2628376/1307) that gives a proof. The comment on the answer gives a reference.